# “Example of” or “example on”?

Tags: word-choice, prepositions

What would be the best way to write this sentence:

> This is an example for Steven **on** how the address would be shown in the popup.

> This is an example for Steven **of** how the address would be shown in the popup.

Comment: The ***for Steven*** bit is syntactically irrelevant. We refer to *examples **of** how to do things*, not ***on***.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is an example for Steven **of** how the address would be shown in the popup.

Comment: Please explain why this is correct. We're not (supposed to be) a free proofreading service.

Answer (score 0):

I would always use "of", however for some unknown reason, I am seeing "on" being used far more often, as far as I was aware, incorrectly. However, common usage is what determines correctness in terms of linguistic evolution.